# Exception thrown by CrudRepository saveAll method if constraint is violated

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data JPA to persist my data into the database. 
The CRUDRepository has the **saveAll(Iterable)** method that I'm using.

Since I have a unique constraint on an entity field, I'm wondering what would happen if I try to save an Interable that contains an Object which is violating this constraint.

Answer (score 6):

Using the standard `saveAll` method, from `SimpleJpaRepository`, you're basically invoking multiple times, once per instance, the `save` method

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {
    // ... Omitted

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

You can see an `EntityManager` instance is used, invoking `persist` or `merge`.
That means its rules apply, and you'll receive a [ConstraintViolationException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/exception/ConstraintViolationException.html).

Comment: I replaced .saveAll method with forEach .save() to allow the exception to occur and still proceed with the list. No other way I could make it work. @Transaction(rollbackon=) didn't work either.